# Using alertblock inside block in tikzposter

Tags: posters, block, tikzposter

Is there a simple way to use `alertblock` inside `\block` in `tikzposter`? I need to emphasize some statement and using `alertblock` will be very practical. Something like:

```
\block{Block Title}{

text text text
text text text

\begin{alertblock}{The Key Idea}
text text text
\end{alertblock}

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please complete your code by adding `\documentclass{...}`, necessary packages and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. That would make it much easier for people to help and make it more likely that their help will actually be applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there's no `alertblock` environment in `tikzposter`, you can use `\innerblock` (with a title) or `\coloredbox` (if no title is needed); refer to the documentation to see all options available for those commands:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{Block Title}{%
text text text text text text
\innerblock[roundedcorners=10pt]{The Key Idea}{text text text}
\coloredbox[fgcolor=red]{text text text}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use the `beamer` skin from [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and design your own block:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{tcbalertblock}[1]{
  beamer,
  colback=Salmon!50!white,
  colframe=FireBrick!75!black,
  adjusted title=#1
}

\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{Block Title}{%
text text text text text text
\innerblock[roundedcorners=10pt]{The Key Idea}{text text text}
\coloredbox[fgcolor=red]{text text text}
\begin{tcbalertblock}{The title}
This box looks like an \texttt{alertedblock} provided by the \texttt{beamer} class.
\end{tcbalertblock}

}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gonzalo Medina, you made my day! :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ArnoldKlein You're welcome! Glad I could help. I updated my answer with another option that might be of interest for you.

Comment: Great! Although yellow block is fine, but I prefer the red one. It's even better. Thanks again!